# Prob. 57, Chap. 1, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: The set of points at which a sequence of continuous functions converges is a ...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

Here is Prob. 57, Chap. 1, in the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Let $\left\{ f_n \right\}$ be a sequence of continuous real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the set of points $x$ at which the sequence $\left\{ f_n(x) \right\}$ converges to a real number is the intersection of a countable collection of $F_\sigma$-sets.

And, an $F_\sigma$-set is a set that can be expressed as the union of countably many closed sets.

My Attempt:

> Let $S$ be the set of all the real numbers $x$ for which the sequence $\left\{ f_n(x) \right\}$ converges to some real number. Let us now define the function $f \colon S \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by the formula
> $$
> f(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x).
> $$

Is the way I've started out likely to reach the desired conclusion? If so, then how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

With problems like this, it is usually more helpful to express the definition of convergence in terms of unions and intersections rather than defining a function on your set. I'll include the full solution below so be warned.

Let $S$ denote the set of points $x$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$ exists. Since a sequence of real numbers is convergent if and only if it is cauchy, we will be using the cauchy condition. As such, $x \in S$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq N$. We can then restate this as $x \in S$ if and only if for all $M \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $N$ with $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq 1/M$ for all $n,m \geq N$. Translating this into unions and intersections we get that $$S = \bigcap_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{m,n \geq N} |f_n - f_m|^{-1}([0, 1/M]).$$ Since $|f_n - f_m|$ is continuous and $[0,1/M]$ is closed, it follows that $\bigcap_{m,n \geq N} |f_n - f_m|^{-1}([0, 1/M])$ is closed. Hence, $S$ is an intersection of $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

Comment: I think you mean intersection of $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Comment: @user900740 Correct. Changed it in an edit.

Comment: Can't we just as easily replace $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq 1/M$ with $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < 1/M$? Then this set would be open, wouldn't it? This part is very confusing, because then the set would not be a F-sigma set, right?

Comment: @SallyG You are correct - although $S$ is usually not open as it involves countable intersections. These are the kinds of freedoms which naturally arise with these kinds of problems. They can be multiple kinds of sets at once. When stating convergence(or cauchy) conditions over the real numbers the definitions are equivalent regardless of which kind of inequality one uses. For example, the usual definition of convergence for a sequence is the same whether or not one uses $< \epsilon$ or $\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: I see. So we can conclude that this is both a intersection of F-sigma sets, and a intersection of a union of G-delta sets. I was wrong to think that it can only be of one type.